# Slope and Curvature values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, srtm, curvature

From an SRTM DEM I have calculated the slope of the terrain with values that range from 0 to 77 (degrees). I have also calculated the curvature of the terrain and the statistical characteristics of the outcome are as shown below:
[image]

What does "e" mean? Is the result of curvature reasonable?

Comment: First, there is an issue in that you are using WGS_1984 for these calculations. You should probably get your data in to a projection like UTM or something. The 'e+' is scientific notation.

Comment: I need my data to be in a geographic coordinate system (lat/lon). For the calculation of curvature and slope I have used a z-factor that is suitable for the latitude of my region (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/06/12/setting-the-z-factor-parameter-correctly/)

Comment: I guess if it needs to be in a GCS, but the blog also says "In terms of best practices, for medium and large scale maps we recommend projecting the DEM before producing a hillshade or doing any analysis."  It's certainly easier to make sense of the data when you are using units like feet or meters.  I really cannot attest to the curvature numbers as I am only familiar with using that tool with data in a PCS. It might also be good to check your slope values by doing a manual computation or two to make sure that it gives what you expect.

Comment: Unless your region is near the Equator, both the slopes and the curvatures you have calculated would be considered unreasonable for most applications.  You need to follow @Tangnar's advice to do the *calculations* in an appropriate coordinate system. You may then reproject the results into any coordinate system you wish.  Do not let your requirements for storing or displaying data interfere with the analysis!