# Units of curvature output in ArcGIS 10.x and Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop

This question has been asked [several](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132768/slope-and-curvature-values) [times](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262894/in-arcmap-what-are-the-units-of-curvature-degrees-100m), but I am not sure that there is a satisfactory answer.

I have used ArcGIS Pro to calculate curvature from a DEM. Now I am not sure what the units are in the curvature raster. According to [ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-curvature-works.htm), the curvature values are calculated using the second derivatives of the input surface in a 3x3 window. Here is an example that comes from my dem. The average elevation is roughly 325 meters, with a cell size of 1 meter. The curvature value for the center cell is -28.8. I obtain the same output using the following code in python. My question is, what does -28.8 (or -0.288, if you don't multiply by 100) mean?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[325.88,325.66,325.73],[325.799,325.670,325.700],[325.920,325.809,325.850]]))


Z1 = df.iloc[0,0]
Z2 = df.iloc[0,1]
Z3 = df.iloc[0,2]
Z4 = df.iloc[1,0]
Z5 = df.iloc[1,1]
Z6 = df.iloc[1,2]
Z7 = df.iloc[2,0]
Z8 = df.iloc[2,1]
Z9 = df.iloc[2,2]

A = ((Z1 + Z3 + Z7 + Z9)/2 - (Z2 + Z4 + Z6 + Z8)/2 + Z5) / 1**4
B = ((Z1 + Z3 - Z7 - Z9)/4 - (Z2 - Z8)/2)/ 1**3
C = ((-Z1 + Z3 - Z7 + Z9) /4 + (Z4 - Z6) /2) / 1**3
D = ((Z4+Z6)/2 - Z5) / 1**2 
E = ((Z2+Z8)/2 - Z5) / 1**2 
F = (-Z1 + Z3 + Z7 - Z9) / (4*1**2) 
G = (-Z4 + Z6) / 2*1

curvature = -2 *(D + E)*100
```

If you change the values to `df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))`, curvature is 0, as expected. If you change the values to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[4,4,4]]))
```

, the value for curvature becomes 100. Again, 100 (or 1) what?

Comment: It is 1/m if your cell size expressed in metres.

Comment: Is 1/m the same as percentage change? I think that the results are in percentage change. In the last example above, the rate of change is 1 meter, and the distance is 1 meter. so rise/run is 1 (or 100, since Arcgis multiplies results by 100).

Comment: If times 100 it's %/m

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't thinking about 1/m correctly.